# Monitor shuts off after installing Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit

Tags: installation, ati, 64-bit, laptop, monitor

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit successfully in nomodeset option, but when I boot the installed system the monitor shuts off, so I would like to know how to fix this like I fixed it in the installation

If someone knows how to solve this problem, his help will be welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your computer has ATI graphics, then the problem might be that you don't have the proper fglrx drivers installed.
Try booting into your installed system with the nomodeset option editing the GRUB entry by pressing "e" when selecting Ubuntu 11.10. After "quiet splash" and before the next thing to it, enter nomodeset.

That will "boot" you into ubuntu, but will actually freeze at the splash. Press Ctrl + Alt + F1 to drop into a console.
Login with your username and your password, and when you're in, type "sudo apt-get install fglrx". These are the proprietary drivers for ATI cards 
Enter your password and install as required.
Reboot and Voilá
...
That worked for me. Might work for you if you have ATI graphics card.
ONLY if you have ATI graphics card.

Answer (score 2):

The `nomodeset` solution should be valid for the installed system as well. When you boot your computer, hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key after the bios logo screen. The GRUB menu should display. Press <kbd>E</kbd> to edit the kernel command line, use the arrow keys to move to the line that says `quiet splash`, and add `nomodeset` there. Then press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot your system.

The boot process should be successful (hopefully). Then you have two options:

1. Make the setting permanent: edit the file `/etc/default/grub` as root by using the command `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` from a terminal, add `nomodeset` after `quiet splash`, save the file, and type on the command line `sudo update-grub`.
2. Try the binary driver for your graphics card. An icon offering to install additional drivers should show up in the top panel; simply follow the instructions there.