# Video output to monitor is cut after installing Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, video, output

I'm a total newbie with Ubuntu, installed Windows numerous times over the years, but this O/S is utterly new to me.
I am trying to install Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit, I have checked the ISO with winMD5sum to ensure that the download was OK. I have burned the image to disc and can see the files in Windows XP's Explorer. I boot up the PC with the disc in the CD-Rom drive, the BIOS is set for CD first boot. The PC starts up, I get an icon at the bottom of the screen (looks like a keyboard, a = and a figure?), then the screens switches off and goes into sleep mode. The CD continues to spin, the light flashes and it appears to be continuing to load for maybe a further 30 seconds. I presume it has then reached the point where it is waiting for me to input a command, but of course I can't do that as the screen is blank.

I then tried I have tried 'nomodeset' as suggested by an experienced Ubuntu used at installation but this only lets it run until the required restart, I tried to enter it at the grub screen on start up but it states 'Error no command exists' (or in very similar words). I then press the Tab key to list all the available commands (about a 100 of them I guess) and nomodeset is not among them.
So I am left with no option other that to continue to boot normally which then turned the screen off 30 seconds later, Ubuntu again sounds like it loaded OK in the background and the start up sound played, at this point there is obviously nothing I can do.

What are the options now?

(Copied from Belarc Advisor:)
MotherBoard: Gigabyte GA-A75M-D2H - Bus Clock: 100 megahertz
3.00 gigahertz AMD A8-3870 APU with Radeon HD Graphics
256 kilobyte primary memory cache
1024 kilobyte tertiary memory cache
64-bit ready
Multi-core (4 total)
Not hyper-threaded
[AMD Radeon HD 6550D [Display adapter] (Onboard graphics, no separate card)
I'm using the motherboard's VGA output rather than the DVI one.

Answer (score 2):

*[OP reported solving the problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107877/video-output-to-monitor-is-cut-after-installing-ubuntu-11-10/243675#243675)*

> after some searching I found a fix that worked for me by [Francisco Martinex askubuntu.com/questions/97475/](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97475/monitor-shuts-off-after-installing-ubuntu-11-10-64-bit/97608#97608)

Answer (score 0):

Install a graphics card other than Radeon. I had exactly the same problem with my shiny new HD6820. I replaced it with a much older and otherwise inferior Gainward 7900GS and it worked first time. (Athlon 64 system). Unless you have a very small case, you should be able to plug in a graphics card and it will take over from the on board system.

Comment: Thanks John, after some searching I found a fix that worked for me  by Francisco Martinex http://askubuntu.com/questions/97475/monitor-shuts-off-after-installing-ubuntu-11-10-64-bit/97608#97608

John, have you been able to use your Gainward card to dual monitor?